# Unity With C# script : Class Data Type Passing Value From Class With Data Twice Weird

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, variables

I got a simple Question and weird from passing value to data type class variable.

the code like below :

```
void AddItem(int ID) {
    for (int i = 0; i < database.items.Count; i++) {
        if(database.items[i].itemID == ID) {
            itemxs = new item (database.items [i].itemName,
                              database.items [i].itemID,
                              database.items [i].itemDesc,
                              database.items [i].harvest,
                              database.items [i].itemTime,
                              database.items [i].stdprice,
                              database.items [i].hightprice,
                              database.items [i].itemStock,
                              database.items [i].Lvlunlock,
                              database.items [i].rawTree,
                              database.items [i].itemType,
                              database.items [i].itemProd,
                              database.items [i].itemIcon);

            Debug.Log ("Item Icon 1 : " + database.items[i].itemIcon); // This appear "Corps/Lemon"
            Debug.Log ("Item Icon 2 : " + itemxs.itemIcon); // This appear "Corps/Lemon/Lemon" **even though I just passing value from code itemxs = new item (database.items [i].itemName,...etc)** it is wierd

            CheckInventoryExist(itemxs);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

itemicon is source from base name : basename + itemName;
database.items[i].itemicon contain ***"Corps/Lemon"***
The Problem is where i debug.log database.items[i].itemicon it still the same string that is *"Corps/Lemon",*
But when i put **"itemxs = new item (database.items [i].itemName,....etc"** and then i debug.log itemxs.itemicon it contain *"Corps/Lemon/Lemon"*

What is going on ?

Thanks

Dennis

Below is the class :

item.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

// Make Class Item
public class item {
    public string itemName;
    public int itemID;
    public string itemDesc;
    public string itemIcon;
    public GameObject itemModel;
    public int itemTime;
    public int hightprice;
    public int stdprice;
    public int itemStock;
    public int harvest;
    public RawTree rawTree;
    public ItemType itemType;
    public ItemProd itemProd;
    public int Lvlunlock;
    private string baseName;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    void Awake () {

    }

    public enum ItemType {
        Raw,
        Admirable,
        Valuable
    }

    public enum RawTree {
        BigTree,
        SmallTree,
        Field,
        None
    }

    public enum ItemProd {
        AnimalBarm,
        Mining,
        Corps,
        Dairy,
        JuiceJamMaker,
        Merchant,
        Kitchen,
        Bakery,
        CraftHouse
    }

    public item (string name, int ID, string desc, int harvestx, int time, int stdpricex, int hightpricex, int stock, int Lvlunlockx, RawTree RawTree, ItemType type, ItemProd prod, string folder) {
        itemName = name;
        itemID = ID;
        itemDesc = desc;
        harvest = harvestx;
        itemTime = time;
        stdprice = stdpricex;
        hightprice = hightpricex;
        itemStock = stock;
        Lvlunlock = Lvlunlockx;
        rawTree = RawTree;
        itemType = type;
        itemProd = prod;
        this.baseName = folder + "/";
        itemIcon = this.baseName + itemName;
    }

    public item() {

    }
}
```

then itemDatabase.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class itemDatabase : MonoBehaviour {
    public List<item> items = new List<item>();

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        // Add Data To Item List With Class Item

        // ------------------------------- Item Corps (Raw - Big Tree) ------------------------------- //
        items.Add (new item ("Lemon", 1, "Honey Lemon", 9, 1020, 75, 158, 0, 1, item.RawTree.BigTree, item.ItemType.Raw, item.ItemProd.Corps, "Corps"));

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

When I put this code :

```
 itemxs = new item (database.items [i].itemName, // This contain "Lemon"
                                      database.items [i].itemID,
                                      database.items [i].itemDesc,
                                      database.items [i].harvest,
                                      database.items [i].itemTime,
                                      database.items [i].stdprice,
                                      database.items [i].hightprice,
                                      database.items [i].itemStock,
                                      database.items [i].Lvlunlock,
                                      database.items [i].rawTree,
                                      database.items [i].itemType,
                                      database.items [i].itemProd,
                                      database.items [i].itemIcon);
```

itemName contain : "Lemon";

ItemICon contain: "Corps/" + itemName; You Can check it in itemDatabase.cs file and the constructor is at item.cs.

so the result itemIcon must be : "Corps/Lemon" But

Why itemxs.itemIcon got double itemName ? for example : "Corps/Lemon/Lemon".

Comment: Can you tell whats happening in this magical constructor code?

Comment: I have update the code with class.. Can you please check it ?

Comment: As sidenote: remove `Start`, `Awake` and `Update` from your `item` class. It does not inherit from `MonoBehaviour` and can't have them because of that (or at least they are not doing the same). Also, class names should allways start with a capital letter.

Answer (score 1):

In `item` constructor you are doing it:

```
this.baseName = folder + "/";
itemIcon = this.baseName + itemName;
```

where `folder == Corps` and `this.baseName == "Corps/Lemon/"` and `itemName == "Lemon"` so you have exactly what you should get.

Comment: In itemDatabase :  items.Add (new item ("Lemon", 1, "Honey Lemon", 9, 1020, 75, 158, 0, 1, item.RawTree.BigTree, item.ItemType.Raw, item.ItemProd.Corps, "Corps")); ....... and the end of parameter i have input "Corps" only. So the this.baseName = folder = "Corps/" without lemon. I have try delete itemName; but itemIcon only contain "Corps/". What is the problem ?

Answer (score -2):

In your constructor:

```
 this.baseName = folder + "/";  // if folder = "Corps/Lemon" from database.items[i].itemIcon
 itemIcon = this.baseName + itemName; // it will update itemIcon to "Corps/Lemon" + "/" + "Lemon"
```

Did you get it now??

You may want to assign `itemIcon` value directly instead of doing all this.

Do this in your constructor :

```
itemIcon = folder;
```

Cheers

Comment: In itemDatabase : items.Add (new item ("Lemon", 1, "Honey Lemon", 9, 1020, 75, 158, 0, 1, item.RawTree.BigTree, item.ItemType.Raw, item.ItemProd.Corps, "Corps")); ....... and the end of parameter i have input "Corps" only. So the this.baseName = folder = "Corps/" without lemon. I have try delete itemName; but itemIcon only contain "Corps/". What is the problem ?

Comment: from your original code: `database.items [i].itemIcon // This Contain "Corps/Lemon");` you are passing `itemIcon` NOT the string "Corps"

Comment: Could you look at this Line at above :   Debug.Log (database.items[i].itemIcon); // While Debug This still contain "Corps/Lemon"
                Debug.Log (itemxs.itemIcon); // While Debug This become contain "Corps/Lemon/Lemon".

Comment: If you will pass `itemIcon` as your folder name this is exactly what should expect. This is accurate behaviour as code doesn't have brain on its own. This surely is a logical error.

Comment: @DennisLiu you don't need to down-vote my answer if you cant understand the basic programming logic. It takes time to read others code and answer question so at least appreciate my help :)

Comment: iam sorry Umair M.. But i am not down-vote you answer.. i am appreciate it..Thanks For you help. But i still cant solve it even i have follow your advice.. Thanks

Comment: What do you want the value of `itemIcon` for `itemxs` ?

Comment: that because i want to passing it into function  CheckInventoryExist(itemxs);  I Have make change to the code above. Thats more detail want i have done. What i want the value for itemxs.itemIcon which is passing from database.items[i].itemIcon is  contain "Corps/Lemon" not "Corps/Lemon/Lemon because the real  database.items[i].itemIcon contain "Corps/Lemon" not "Coprs/Lemon/Lemon.

Comment: then my answer is right for you. Replace those 2 lines in code with `itemIcon = folder;` and this will solve your problem

Comment: Thanks Umair.. But i already solve it.. The problem is on itemDatabase.cs i have start it first. and then i passing value again.. I have make some change before.. Thanks..

Comment: glad to know that :)