# Unity With C# script : Class Data Type Passing Value From Class Data Twice Weird

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, parameter-passing

I got a simple Question and weird from passing value to data type class variable.

The code below :

itemDatabase.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class itemDatabase : MonoBehaviour {
    public List<item> items = new List<item>();

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        // Add Data To Item List With Class Item

        // ------------------------------- Item Corps (Raw - Big Tree) ------------------------------- //
        items.Add (new item ("Lemon", 1, "Honey Lemon", 9, 1020, 75, 158, 0, 1, item.RawTree.BigTree, item.ItemType.Raw, item.ItemProd.Corps, "Corps"));

    }

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
```

}

Constructor :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

// Make Class Item
public class item {
    public string itemName;
    public int itemID;
    public string itemDesc;
    public string itemIcon;
    public GameObject itemModel;
    public int itemTime;
    public int hightprice;
    public int stdprice;
    public int itemStock;
    public int harvest;
    public RawTree rawTree;
    public ItemType itemType;
    public ItemProd itemProd;
    public int Lvlunlock;
    private string baseName;

    public enum ItemType {
        Raw,
        Admirable,
        Valuable
    }

    public enum RawTree {
        BigTree,
        SmallTree,
        Field,
        None
    }

    public enum ItemProd {
        AnimalBarm,
        Mining,
        Corps,
        Dairy,
        JuiceJamMaker,
        Merchant,
        Kitchen,
        Bakery,
        CraftHouse
    }

public item (string name, int ID, string desc, int harvestx, int time, int stdpricex, int hightpricex, int stock, int Lvlunlockx, RawTree RawTree, ItemType type, ItemProd prod, string folderx) {
    itemName = name;
    itemID = ID;
    itemDesc = desc;
    harvest = harvestx;
    itemTime = time;
    stdprice = stdpricex;
    hightprice = hightpricex;
    itemStock = stock;
    Lvlunlock = Lvlunlockx;
    rawTree = RawTree;
    itemType = type;
    itemProd = prod;
    **// line : 60 
    // itemName contain : "Lemon" // folderx contain : "Corps"**
    this.baseName = folderx + "/"; **// basename is directory source picture**
    itemIcon = this.baseName + itemName;
    Debug.Log ("item name : " + itemName); **// result : "Lemon"**
    Debug.Log ("item icon : " + itemIcon); **// result : "Corps/Lemon/Lemon" Why this appear "Corps/Lemon/Lemon" not "Corps/Lemon" ???? this is a mistake right ??**
    Debug.Log ("this.basename : " + this.baseName); **// result : "Corps/Lemon" why this appear "Corps/Lemon" not "corps/" ???? this is also a mistake right ???**
}
```

this.baseName is source of directory picture for examples :

this.baseName = "Corps/Lemon". So it from Folder "Corps" file "Lemon".
this.baseName = folderx + "/"; folderx is input from itemDatabase : items.Add (new item ("Lemon", 1, "Honey Lemon", 9, 1020, 75, 158, 0, 1, item.RawTree.BigTree, item.ItemType.Raw, item.ItemProd.Corps, "Corps")); // "Corps" refer to folderx

//Add Item Method

```
void AddItem(int ID) {
        for (int i = 0; i < database.items.Count; i++) {
            if(database.items[i].itemID == ID) {
                itemxs = new item (database.items [i].itemName,
                                  database.items [i].itemID,
                                  database.items [i].itemDesc,
                                  database.items [i].harvest,
                                  database.items [i].itemTime,
                                  database.items [i].stdprice,
                                  database.items [i].hightprice,
                                  database.items [i].itemStock,
                                  database.items [i].Lvlunlock,
                                  database.items [i].rawTree,
                                  database.items [i].itemType,
                                  database.items [i].itemProd,
                                  database.items [i].itemIcon);
                // Line 80
                Debug.Log ("Item Icon 1 : " + database.items[i].itemIcon); // result "Corps/Lemon"
                Debug.Log ("Item Icon 2 : " + itemxs.itemIcon); // result "Corps/Lemon/Lemon";

                CheckInventoryExist(itemxs);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem start from line 60 and line 80 (at Add item method) as you can see i just passing the value from

```
itemxs = new item (database.items [i].itemName,
                                      database.items [i].itemID,
                                      database.items [i].itemDesc,
                                      database.items [i].harvest,
                                      database.items [i].itemTime,
                                      database.items [i].stdprice,
                                      database.items [i].hightprice,
                                      database.items [i].itemStock,
                                      database.items [i].Lvlunlock,
                                      database.items [i].rawTree,
                                      database.items [i].itemType,
                                      database.items [i].itemProd,
                                      database.items [i].itemIcon);
```

this when i debug got wierd value.

```
  // Line 80
Debug.Log ("Item Icon 1 : " + database.items[i].itemIcon); // result "Corps/Lemon"
            Debug.Log ("Item Icon 2 : " + itemxs.itemIcon); // result "Corps/Lemon/Lemon";
```

Any Idea ??

Dennis

Comment: there is not enough information to check. Need more code. Why not add code where you modify the folderx and baseName?

Comment: is that enough ? please check it..

Comment: what is baseName? datatype please put some more details

Comment: i have make some change to the code for more detail. Please check it.. Thanks

Comment: it is giving correct value. Check by debugging the values. Iam sure you are changing somewhere else. I just checked with  your code http://imgur.com/zcdak9v

Comment: hey killer_mech, please check again i have update more complete code. Thats confused me with the result..

Comment: You duplicated the question - at least there is same here and it got two answers - both correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity With C# script : Class Data Type Passing Value From Class With Data Twice Weird](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38072879/unity-with-c-sharp-script-class-data-type-passing-value-from-class-with-data-t)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this:
You create an item in your first snippet in `Start`. This should result in an correct item.

Now, for your `itemxs` you create an item by using the values of an existing item.

With values:

```
Item1:
    itemName == "Lemon"
    baseName == "Corps/"
    itemIcon == "Corps/Lemon"
```

When you feed this in the constructor of `itemxs` it will look like this (the values you pass to the constructor):

```
Item(string name == "Lemon", ..., string folderx == "Corps/Lemon")
```

The reason is that you actually pass `database.items [i].itemIcon` in `AddItem`, not only `"Corps"` as you did in the first snippet.

That is where your copying fails. I actually recommend to have a look for `c# copy constructor`.

Comment: yahh..i got it.. Do you have any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: Change the content of the constructor or, as stated in my last sentence, have a look on copy constructors. This will also save you quite a bit of typing if you have multiple places where you want to copy an item from your database.